# ROS2 on QNX byte-compilation error

Tags: ros2

I was trying to build ROS2(foxy & galactic) on QNX(SDP7.1) with the link mentioned below. While building I am getting an error with multiple warnings as "byte-compiling is skipping" and many packages are not building following the above warnings.

Link : https://ros2-qnx-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/foxy/build_from_source.html

The produced output:

````
Starting >>> gmock_vendor
--- stderr: ament_cppcheck                                                                                                                                                             
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_cppcheck [1.57s]
--- stderr: ament_uncrustify                                                                                                                                                                            
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_uncrustify [1.64s]
--- stderr: ament_lint                                                                                                                                                        
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_lint [1.84s]
--- stderr: ament_package                                                                                                                                                                            
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_package [1.96s]
Starting >>> ament_cmake_core
Starting >>> ament_flake8
--- stderr: ament_pycodestyle                                                                                                                                                                             
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_pycodestyle [1.80s]
--- stderr: osrf_pycommon
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
--- stderr: ament_pyflakes                                                                                                                                                                                
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_pyflakes [0.91s]
--- stderr: ament_flake8                                                                                                                                                          
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Starting >>> ros_environment                                                                                                                                                                            
[7.897s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_cmake.task.cmake.build:Could not run installation step for package 'test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp' because it has no 'install' target                                      
Finished <<< test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp [1.22s]                                                                                                                         

                                                                                                                     
Starting >>> ament_cmake_export_interfaces                                                                                                                        
--- stderr: ament_pep257                                                                                                                                          
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_pep257 [2.60s]
--- stderr: ament_mypy                                                                                                                                                                       
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_mypy [2.65s]
Starting >>> ament_copyright                                                                                                                                             
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_include_directories [2.58s]                                                                                                              
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_link_flags [2.74s]                                                                                                                       
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_definitions [2.91s]                                                                                                                       
Finished <<< ament_cmake_include_directories [3.04s]                                                                                                                     
Starting >>> ament_cmake_target_dependencies
Finished <<< ament_cmake_python [3.19s]                                                                                                                                                        
Finished <<< test_interface_files [3.13s]                                                                                                                                                                 
Starting >>> ament_cmake_test
Finished <<< ros_environment [3.35s]                                                                                                                                
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_targets [2.20s]                                                                                                                                  
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_dependencies [2.58s]                                                                                                                                
Finished <<< ament_cmake_export_interfaces [2.35s]                                                                                                           
--- stderr: ament_copyright                                                                                                                                                              
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_copyright [1.78s]
Starting >>> domain_coordinator
Starting >>> ament_xmllint                                                                                                                                                                  
Starting >>> ament_index_python
Starting >>> ament_lint_cmake
Starting >>> ament_cpplint                                                                                                                                                                      
Starting >>> ament_clang_format
Starting >>> ament_clang_tidy                                                                                                                                                                   
Starting >>> ament_pclint
Finished <<< ament_cmake_target_dependencies [2.78s]                                                                                                                                                 
Finished <<< ament_cmake_test [2.65s]                                                                                                                                                               
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_lint_cmake [2.32s]
--- stderr: ament_clang_tidy                                                                                                                                                                             
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_clang_tidy [2.28s]
--- stderr: ament_cpplint                                                                                                                                                     
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_cpplint [2.44s]
--- stderr: ament_pclint                                                                                                                                                                 
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_pclint [2.40s]
--- stderr: ament_clang_format                                                                                                                                                                    
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< ament_clang_format [2.56s]
Starting >>> ament_cmake_lint_cmake
Starting >>> rpyutils
Starting >>> launch
Starting >>> tracetools_trace                                                                                                                                         
Starting >>> tracetools_read
Finished <<< ament_cmake_nose [2.25s]                                                                                                                                          
Finished <<< ament_cmake_gtest [2.46s]                                                                                                                                         
Finished <<< ament_cmake [2.59s]                                                                                                                                                         
Starting >>> ament_cmake_gmock
Starting >>> foonathan_memory_vendor                                                                                                                                                              
Starting >>> tinyxml2_vendor
Starting >>> yaml_cpp_vendor
Starting >>> shared_queues_vendor
Starting >>> ament_cmake_auto                                                                                                                                                                      
Starting >>> eigen3_vendor
Starting >>> zstd_vendor
Finished <<< ament_lint_auto [2.85s]                                                                                                                                                               
--- stderr: rpyutils
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< rpyutils [1.97s]
Starting >>> numpy_vendor
Starting >>> sqlite3_vendor                                                                                                                                                         
--- stderr: launch                                                                                                                                                                  
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< launch [2.09s]
Finished <<< ament_cmake_google_benchmark [3.16s]                                                                                                                                             
Finished <<< ament_cmake_pytest [3.31s]                                                                                                                                                             
Starting >>> launch_testing
Starting >>> launch_xml
Starting >>> apr_vendor                                                                                                                                                                          
--- stderr: tracetools_read                                                                                                                                           
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< tracetools_read [2.57s]
--- stderr: tracetools_trace                                                                                                                                                        
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< tracetools_trace [2.70s]
Starting >>> bullet3_vendor                                                                                                                                                              
Starting >>> cyclonedds_vendor
Finished <<< ament_cmake_lint_cmake [3.25s]                                                                                                                                              
Starting >>> ament_cmake_copyright
Finished <<< ament_cmake_auto [2.12s]                                                                                                                                                         
Starting >>> opencv_vendor
Finished <<< ament_cmake_gmock [2.40s]                                                                                                                                                        
Starting >>> launch_yaml
Finished <<< sqlite3_vendor [2.11s]                                                                                                                                                                
--- stderr: launch_xml
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< launch_xml [1.83s]
--- stderr: launch_testing                                                                                                                                                                         
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< launch_testing [1.95s]
Starting >>> libcurl_vendor
Starting >>> libxslt_vendor                                                                                                                                                                        
Starting >>> libpng16_vendor
--- stderr: launch_yaml                                                                                                                                                                              
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

---
Finished <<< launch_yaml [3.99s]
Starting >>> pybind11_vendor
Finished <<< ament_cmake_copyright [4.96s]                                                                                                                                                           
Starting >>> ament_cmake_cppcheck
Finished <<< shared_queues_vendor [8.51s]                                                                                                                                                         
--- stderr: tinyxml2_vendor                                                                                                                                                           
Cloning into 'tinyxml2'...
Note: switching to 'bf15233ad88390461f6ab0dbcf046cce643c5fcb'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at bf15233 Setting the version to 8.0.0
---
Finished <<< tinyxml2_vendor [8.68s]
Starting >>> ament_cmake_cpplint
Starting >>> ament_cmake_uncrustify                                                                                                                                                 
Finished <<< libcurl_vendor [6.18s]                                                                                                                                                 
Starting >>> ament_cmake_flake8
--- stderr: yaml_cpp_vendor                                                                                                                                                         
Cloning into 'yaml_cpp'...
Note: switching to '9a3624205e8774953ef18f57067b3426c1c5ada6'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 9a36242 Update version to 0.6.3.
---
Finished <<< yaml_cpp_vendor [8.95s]
Starting >>> ament_cmake_pep257
--- stderr: eigen3_vendor                                                                                                                                                            
Cloning into 'eigen3'...
Switched to a new branch '3.3'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
---
Finished <<< eigen3_vendor [10.1s]
Starting >>> ament_cmake_xmllint
Finished <<< ament_cmake_cppcheck [4.42s]                                                                                                                                            
Starting >>> eigen3_cmake_module
--- stderr: foonathan_memory_vendor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
variables.c: In function 'xsltReleaseRVT':
variables.c:378:6: warning: 'xmlFreeRefTable' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      xmlFreeRefTable((xmlRefTablePtr) RVT->refs);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/parser.h:17,
                 from /home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/globals.h:18,
                 from /home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/threads.h:35,
                 from /home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/xmlmemory.h:220,
                 from variables.c:17:
/home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/valid.h:294:3: note: declared here
   xmlFreeRefTable        (xmlRefTablePtr table);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
functions.c: In function 'xsltDocumentFunctionLoadDocument':
functions.c:195:2: warning: case value '5' not in enumerated type 'xmlXPathObjectType' {aka 'enum <anonymous>'} [-Wswitch]
  case XPATH_POINT:
  ^~~~ 
functions.c:198:2: warning: case value '6' not in enumerated type 'xmlXPathObjectType' {aka 'enum <anonymous>'} [-Wswitch]
  case XPATH_RANGE:
  ^~~~
functions.c:199:2: warning: case value '7' not in enumerated type 'xmlXPathObjectType' {aka 'enum <anonymous>'} [-Wswitch]
  case XPATH_LOCATIONSET:
  ^~~~
transform.c: In function 'xsltNewTransformContext':
transform.c:640:5: warning: 'xmlXPathInit' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     xmlXPathInit();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from transform.c:34:
/home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/xpath.h:564:7: note: declared here
       xmlXPathInit  (void);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xsltproc.c: In function 'main':
xsltproc.c:561:5: warning: 'xmlInitMemory' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     xmlInitMemory();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/tree.h:1308,
                 from ../libexslt/exslt.h:5,
                 from xsltproc.c:11:
/home/eaahila04/qnx710_ros2/target/qnx7/usr/include/libxml/xmlmemory.h:131:2: note: declared here
  xmlInitMemory (void);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
libtool: warning: relinking 'libexslt.la'
---
Finished <<< libxslt_vendor [33.7s]
Starting >>> lxml_vendor                                                                                                                                                        
Finished <<< rosidl_generator_dds_idl [4.35s]                                                                                                                                   
--- stderr: rcutils                                                                                                                                                             
/home/eaahila04/ros2_foxy/src/ros2/rcutils/src/strerror.c: In function 'rcutils_strerror':
/home/eaahila04/ros2_foxy/src/ros2/rcutils/src/strerror.c:32:16: warning: initialization of 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   char * msg = strerror_r(errno, buffer, buffer_length);
                ^~~~~~~~~                                           
```
````